Post-apocalyptic TV movie from the '70s or '80s
I can't remember the name of this TV movie. Does anyone remember it?
It starts out in the present (which was the '70s or '80s when the movie came out), and a reporter or researcher is driving in his car near Los Angeles and is studying or measuring the effects of smog or something. It is very hot and he ends up falling asleep on the side of the road. He then wakes up in the future (the year 2025, or 2525, or something like that). Everyone is living in an underground society because the atmosphere is too polluted to live on the surface. It was crowded with a lot of tension and some violence. I don't remember a whole lot else about the movie. At the end of the movie the reporter wakes back up in his car and realizes it was all a dream. It was supposed to be a cautionary tale of what could happen if we pollute the air too badly.
I always thought the movie was called L.A. 2025 or something like that but I can't find any matches.
It was a bit like THX-1138 but there were no underground highways or cars. Anyone have any idea what that TV movie was called?

After some googling, I think it is this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L.A._2017

"L.A. 2017" is a 1971 episode of the NBC television series The Name of the Game.  

The plot summary (emphasis mine): 

A publisher, Glenn Howard (Gene Barry), finds himself suddenly plunged 46 years into the future only to learn that the people of Los Angeles are living underground to escape the pollution. A fascist America is run like a corporation with a number of vice-presidents. The police department of the subterranean Los Angeles is led/managed by psychiatrists.
  At the end, Howard wakes up to discover it was all a dream—although there is a chilling final image of dead birds that hint at a troubled future ahead.


Yes, I believe that was it. Thank-you so much for finding the name of it for me. It always bugged me that I could not remember or find it again.

@Steve If the answer is correct, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it. This effectively resolves the question.
